# assigning a value to a list of arrays

Tags: python

I am new to numpy and wanted to know how can I assign a value to a list of array. In C++ I can do `array[i][j] = 1`
How can I do that for numpy?
For example if I have:
`array = np.array([[0,0], [0, 1], [0, 2]])`
how can I assign `[0, 0]` to have a value of, say, `1`?

thank you all

Comment: Did you try the C syntax?

Comment: that isnt a list of arrays. That is a single numpy array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list_of_arrays` is not a good name for the variable because it is a 2d numpy array and not a list. That said, literally all that you need to do is `list_of_arrays[0, 0] = 1`. You should not attempt to do `list_of_arrays[0][0] = 1` like in C++ - it will work but it will be much less efficient because it constructs an temporary object for the sub-array.

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> list_of_arrays = np.array([[0,0], [0, 1], [0, 2]])

>>> list_of_arrays
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2]])

>>> list_of_arrays[0, 0] = 1

>>> list_of_arrays
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2]])
```

Comment: Klaus D "Did you try the C syntax"? Please don't encourage him to do that because it will appear to work but it is not good practice for the reason I have stated, and it will then teach a bad habit which will be more difficult to "unlearn" later.

Comment: I was just wondering that y this is not a good practice? @pacharan

Comment: @subhanshukumar It will create a temporary object which contains a view of a slice of the original array, and then use that temporary object in order to assign one of the elements, before discarding that temporary object -- when the whole thing could have been done by doing a 2d index from the original array. So it is quite an inefficient solution.